# How do I get my composer package autoloaded properly?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have created a package to separate out business logic into easier to distribute modules. The composer file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "aggiq/johnny-cash",
    "description": "A collection of controllers, models, migrations, and tests for a phonebanking backend.",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [ ... ],
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": ">=5.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Johnny\\Phonebanking\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

And our source files are indeed in src/:

src/Controllers/PhonebankController.php
   src/Models/Phonebank.php
   ...

I saved and pushed this to our gitlab repo, and then included it as a dependency in a test project:

```
{
    ...,
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "aggiq/johnny-cash",
            "version": "0.1",
            "type": "package",
            "source": {
                "url": "gitlab url",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "dev"
            }
        }
    }],
    "require": {
        "aggiq/johnny-cash": "*",
    },
    ...
}
```

And when I do composer update, it successfully grabs the project and downloads it into the vendor folder:

```
vendor/aggiq/johnny-cash/Controllers/PhonebankController.php
...
```

However, when I look in the test project's autoload_psr4.php, it's not there. Is there a step I missed?

Edit: updates the directories to have capital letters to match the namespaces, and here is the generated PSR4 php file:

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. We needed to do two things.

1. The repository type specified in the parent pacakge should be `vcs` not `package` since we are loading from a git server:

   "repositories": [{
       "type": "vcs",
       "url": "git@xxx.git"
   }]
2. The package type in the child package should be `library`:

   "type": "library"

Once those two changes were made, composer update installed not only the child package but also its dependencies, proving it is being recognized by composer.

Answer (score 0):

You have registered autoloading at your package's `composer.json` correctly:

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "Johnny\\Phonebanking\\": "src/"
   }
}
```

This means, any class in `Johnny\Phonebanking` namespace will be in `src` directory. E.g.:

- `Johnny\Phonebanking\SomeClass` => `src/SomeClass.php`
- `Johnny\Phonebanking\SomeNamespace\AnotherClass` => `src/SomeNamespace\AnotherClass.php`

As you can see, **it has to respect *CapitalLetters***.

Saying that, you should correct first letters of your directories, from:

```
src/controllers/PhonebankController.php
src/models/Phonebank.php
```

to

```
src/Controllers/PhonebankController.php
src/Models/Phonebank.php
```

Comment: I have renamed the directories to `src/Controllers`, `src/Models`, etc as you suggested, and reimported the project into my base project. I can confirm the directories in the `vendor/` folder. However running `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` do not add the classes to the psr4 autoload file. Sorry!

Comment: Only prefixes and their locations shoudl be in `autoload_psr4.php`, not specific files. If `"Johnny\\Phonebanking\\"` is missing there, add the content of the file to your question please.

Comment: Could you temporarily allow access to the package? I want to test it.
Also, is your problem really in empty `autoload_psr4.php` or that classes are not autoloaded? Have you tried them in your code? I ask because it might not be related, as composer has many (optimized) ways to load content.